# Blur text colour

Tags: css

I am trying to add bright blurred colour to my text, I tried using box shadow, but the outcome is too dark:
How can I make it brighter?

```css
    text-shadow: #fff 1px 0 10px;
```

[image]

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple shadows at once to make it more shiny:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  text-shadow: #fff 1px 0 10px, #fff 1px 0 10px, #fff 1px 0 10px, #fff 1px 0 10px, #fff 1px 0 10px, #fff 1px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>MY WHATEVER</div>
```